# Area of convex hull of 6 points greater than twice the sum of the areas of 2 triangles formed by the 6 points

Tags: geometry, area

I noticed something interesting but I couldn't prove it to the end.

I want to prove that if I have $6$ coplanar points and the area of convex hull of these points is equal to $P$, then I can mark the points with $A,B,C,D,E,F$ so that the sum of areas of triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ is less or equal to $\frac{P}{2}$.

I proved that I always can mark that points if the convex hull has $3$ or $4$ vertices, but there still remain cases with $5$ and $6$ vertices.

Comment: You just need the two triangles to be disjoint, right?

Comment: What is your proof for $3$ and $4$? Maybe it can be extended into $5$ and $6$?

Comment: These triangle don't need to bee disjoint. I am almost sure that my proof for 3 and 4 cannot be extended into 5 or 6 because I was just dividing the area of convex hull into smaller areas with triangular shape. in case of 3 vertices you can always find six disjoint triangles defined with given 6 points then the sum of these six areas is smaller than P so one pair of triangles has area smaller than P/3. Similar thing for case with 4, difference is that I can find 4 triangles instead of 6 so the coefficient is now 1/2. But for 5 or 6 I need something else, I cannot just split the area.